# Assigning column values in a 2D array into individual clusters

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have difficulties in assigning values in a 2D array into clusters based on their sorted values. Might be a little bit hard to understand but I'll explain the best that I could.

I have a 2D matrix as below.

```
[5.2, 3.0, 4.4, 6.1]
[0.1, 1.0, 6.9, 4.5]
[3.1, 3.3, 5.9, 1.3]
```

Now, I would want to iterate the first column in each row and assign cluster (could be an array/list) to each of the column cell values.

So, the lowest value in a 2D column will be assign to cluster 1, second lowest will be assign to cluster 2, third lowest will be assign to cluster 3. Then it will move on to the next column and redo.

For example:

```
First column
5.2 (3rd lowest value -> assign to cluster 3)
0.1 (lowest value -> assign to cluster 1)
3.1 (2nd lowest value -> assign to cluster 2)
```

...then proceed to the second column. The thing is, the column and row are dynamic so I couldn't use a static variable for cluster array(number of cluster may change).

So finally when everything is clustered, the output from each cluster will contain something like this:

```
double[] cluster1 = 0.1, 1.0, 4.4, 1.3; //contains the lowest value in each column
double[] cluster2 = 3.1, 3.0, 5.9, 4.5; //contains the 2nd lowest value in each column
double[] cluster3 = 5.2, 3.3, 6.9, 6.1 //contains the 3nd lowest value in each column
--- and if there's more row, number of cluster may increase...
```

This is the code that I attempted to do so far but this only get the lowest value from each column...

```
  int dynamicCol = 4;
  int dynamicRow = 3;

  for(int col=0;col<dynamicCol;col++)
  {
         for(int row = 0; row < dynamicRow; row++)
         {
             colArray[row] = cluster[row][col];
         }          
     System.out.println("Min in col "+(col+1)+": "+getMin(colArray));//this will find the lowest value in each column and store in an array
         cluster1.add(getMin(colArray));//store the lowest value in each column into cluster 1
     }

//getMin function to get lowest value in each column
 public static double getMin(double[] inputArray){ 
    double minValue = inputArray[0]; 
    for(int i=1;i<inputArray.length;i++){ 
      if(inputArray[i] < minValue){ 
        minValue = inputArray[i]; 
      } 
    } 
    return minValue; 
  }
```

Appreciate help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest using this as is but might help

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int[][] data = new int[][]{ {1,4,3},
                                {2,1,4},
                                {3,2,1},
                                {4,3,2}};
    int row = data.length;
    int col = data[0].length;

    System.err.println(row+" rows");
    System.err.println(col + " columns");

    List<List<Integer>> clusters = new ArrayList<>(row);
    for(int i=0; i< row; i++){
        clusters.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(col));
    }

    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(col);

    for(int i=0; i< col; i++){
        temp.clear();
        for(int j=0; j< row; j++){
            temp.add(data[j][i]);
        }
        System.err.println(temp);
        Collections.sort(temp);
        for(int x = 0; x < row; x++){
            clusters.get(x).add(temp.get(x));
        }
    }
    System.err.println("Results");
    System.err.println(clusters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.sort()` method to sort each row of your array, then you can put each column value in the cluster of the same position.

```
        int[][] my2DArray = new int[][]{
            {1,4,3},
            {2,1,4},
            {3,2,1},
            {4,3,2}};
    // Initialize list of clusters.
    List<List<Integer>> clusters = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < my2DArray.length; i++) {
        clusters.add(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    for (int[] column : my2DArray) {
        Arrays.sort(column);
        for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
            clusters.get(i).add(column[i]); // Add the value to the cluster
        }
    }
```